# Sort the index of an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array that looks like this: `a[]={2,3,4,5,8,2,5,6}`.
Now I want to sort the indexes ,but keep the original array intact, and get something like this `a_index[]={0,5,1,2,3,6,7,4}`...

I have an `O(N^2)` algorithm for this. Can someone give me a better one (preferably `O(NlogN)`)?

Answer (score 4):

Create a struct that contains two fields: `index` and `value`.

Create an array of this structs, where each element (struct) is the original index and value of an element in the array.

Sort the struct using ONLY the value in O(nlogn).

When you are done - iterate the array in the sorted order to get the sorted indices.

Comment: Thanks .. I will try that .. Couldn't think of struct !!

Answer (score 3):

use `qsort`
E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *TheArray;

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int ia = *(int *)a;
    int ib = *(int *)b;
    return (TheArray[ia] > TheArray[ib]) - (TheArray[ia] < TheArray[ib]);
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {2,3,4,5,8,2,5,6};
    size_t len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    int a_index[len];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        a_index[i] = i;

    TheArray = a;
    qsort(a_index, len, sizeof(*a_index), cmp);

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%d ", a_index[i]);//5 0 1 2 6 3 7 4 : qsort is not a stable.
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qsort worse complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: I knew that. Then what algo is used for qsort()?

Comment: I do not know to be honest.

Comment: It says that It is that first use what is already.

It is not too late to create from it if there is a problem with the performance.

Comment: Quicksort gained widespread adoption, appearing, for example, in Unix as the default library sort function, hence it lent its name to the C standard library function qsort and in the reference implementation of Java. (See history) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82400/discussion-between-nafeeur-rahman-and-bluepixy).

Comment: Currently name to is only leave its mark, and the go and assume the algorithm is quicksort is is incorrect.

Comment: @NafeeurRahman  Please tell me if quicksort is stated to have used it in the C standard.

Comment: For reference : read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) Notes.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this essentially be solveable with an implementation of any sorting algorithm, with the following adjustment:

Where normally you would compare something like:
`if (a[x] < a[x+1])`

You will now be doing:
`if (a[a_index[x]] < a[a_index[x+1]])`

And instead of:
`swap(a[x], a[x+1])`

You'll be doing:
`swap(a_index[x], a_index[x+1])`

(Where a_index is initialized to contain the range of indexes in sequential order initially (0..sizeof(a))

Since essentially a_index is just a lookup-table, where the value for the purpose of sorting is the corresponding value in a. (In practice this is just another level of indirection compared to what we normally do when we sort, as normally we wouldn't compare (x) and (x+1) directly either)

A similar solution can be done without doing in-place sorting as well, as long as you perform all your comparisons against the corresponding values in a, instead of comparing the